# How to test django logout using client.post()?

Tags: python, django, testing

I want to test if my user is logged out correctly. I can log in. I tried to logou the same way, but, the test fails. I can't figure out why.

Why this test fails?

```
def test_user_can_login_and_logout(self):
    response = self.client.post('/login/', {'username': 'login', 'password': 'pass'})
    user = auth.get_user(self.client)
    self.assertEqual(user.is_authenticated(), True)   # This works fine
    self.client.post('/logout/')
    self.assertEqual(user.is_authenticated(), False)  # This fails.
```

My `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
        (...)
        url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'home/login.html'}, name='login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
        (...)
        ]
```

In question I skipped the code responsible for creating test user in database.

Comment: What fails with this code, precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the post is going to modify another copy of the user object. Try getting the User instance again after you logout.

Also, make sure you asset the response of your post so you can confirm the post was successful.